# How to tell if app .war file is finished deploying in Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I copied my app.war in webapps folder.

Started the server using **`startup.bat`** command.

How to check if my war file is deployed ?

Comment: By accessing the app, a manager, JMX or a LifeCycleListener.

Comment: [Answer for Linux environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68262766/2834978)