# Monitor tomcat in Bash until it finishes deploying war or application

Tags: bash, eclipse, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat-manager

How could **Tomcat** be monitored in a bash script to detect that it finished deploying a war or application?

Scenarios:

- Tomcat started with `systemd`
- Tomcat started with `catalina.sh`
- Using Tomcat Manager
- Tomcat started from Eclipse
- Embedded Tomcat on SpringBoot

My answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With `systemd`**
If you start Tomcat with systemctl or catalina.sh uses systemctl something like this could be done.
Change `demo.war` to your war name, Adjust the sleep period to show as many `.` (dots) as needed. If it takes 30 secs to deploy, it will show 30 dots.

```
while ! systemctl status tomcat --no-pager | grep -q 'Deployment of.*demo.war.* has finished'; do \
echo -ne "."; sleep 1; \
done && echo "War deployed"
```

**With `catalina.sh`**
If `catalina.sh run` from [Apache package](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/bin/catalina.sh) is used (using `catalina.sh start` will not work)

```
while read -r line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -q 'Deployment of.*[/]demo.war.* has finished' ; then
        echo "***** $line"
        # do some stuff with your app
        break
    else
        echo "---- $line"
    fi
done < <(./bin/catalina.sh run 2>&1 &) && echo "War deployed"
# start tomcat ----------^
# with console output but in background

./bin/catalina.sh stop
```

**Monitoring log file**
Might required permissions to the log file.

```
log='/var/log/tomcat/catalina.2021-07-05.log'
msg='Deployment of.*[/]demo.war.* has finished'
while read -r line; do
    if echo "$line" | grep -q "$msg" ; then
        echo "***** $line"
        # do some stuff with your app
        break
    else
        echo "---- $line"
    fi
done < <(tail -n 1 -f "$log")
echo "War deployed"
sleep 5 # get a chance to see the previous message :-p
```

If starting tomcat from Eclipse

```
log='/home/lmc/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/logs/catalina.out'
msg='Deployment of deployment descriptor .*demo.xml. has finished'
# same code as above
```

**With Tomcat Manager**
With [Tomcat manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) configured:

```
until ! curl -u userblah:s3cr3t --silent "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list" | grep '^[/]demo:running'; do
    echo "Deploying 'demo' app"
    sleep 1
done
```

**With SpringBoot Actuator**
If your Spring boot app uses [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.17.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html) and is configured as

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
management.server.port=8081
management.server.address=127.0.0.1
```

It can be monitored as:

```
until curl --silent "http://127.0.0.1:8081/actuator/health" | grep -q 'status":"UP'; do
    echo "Deploying 'demo' app"
    sleep 1
done
echo "is UP"
```