# How to detect that all WARs are fully deployed and operational in Tomcat? (in other words, not starting or stopping)

Tags: tomcat, deployment, web-applications

I need a way to verify that **all** Apps/WARs on a Tomcat 10 server are fully deployed and operational.

I can manually see the apps deployment status in the logs, and in the provided Tomcat **WebApplicationManager/ListApplications**, so it must be possible.

But I googled extensively and I did not find a solution.

QUESTIONS:

1. Is there a Tomcat REST service or API that gives a Boolean response "all Applications are up and running"?
2. If no, is there an API that I can call to find the list of apps that tomcat wants to deploy and whether they are fully deployed and operational at the moment of querying?
3. If still no can you suggest of a simple way to achieve what I need?

FALLBACK:

If there are no easy solution I plan to look at the Tomcat Web Application Manager and copy its code for finding the list of applications and their status, and expose it through a REST service.   But I hope there is a simpler option.

Comment: [Here there are some ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262765/monitor-tomcat-in-bash-until-it-finishes-deploying-war-or-application) to do that. THe Tomcat Manager could be a good one. I will investigate the jmx option when time allows.

Comment: Thanks, the concept of parsing the Tomcat Manager page does indeed look promising.   I think I should be able to write a utility java method that parses both the list of apps and whether they are up.

Comment: [ManagerServlet.isDeployed(name)](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/ManagerServlet.java#L1448)

Comment: That helps and also points me to clues as to the other bits that I need, like the list of webapps.